# Specific Meta Tags For Blog Post For Search Engines

Tags: asp.net, html, seo, meta-tags

I am wondering what kind of tags can be used in a web page of a blog post to give search bots more clue about what they are looking at.

The ones that I know is as follows :

- keywords meta tag
- description meta tag
- <strike>canonical meta tag</strike>

Also rel="canonical" link as follows :

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish"/>
```

Is there any others?

Comment: I think the person who has voted this post to be closed needs to sing him/herself out from here. How could this be an off-topic question for the god's sake.

Comment: This is off topic because it isn't a programming question and belongs at Pro Webmasters. Once it is migrated there it will be closed as an exact duplicate of [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/593/which-meta-tags-are-not-worth-the-effort) or [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/new-meta-tags-with-positive-effects-for-seo-ranking-in-2011-and-beyond).

Comment: @John it is certainly not duplicate. didn't you see the question title : _Specific Meta Tags For **Blog Post** For Search Engines_

Comment: Blog posts aren't special in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, meta description and content tags are no longer used by the major search engines for the purposes of any kind of page/site ranking. However, I still include them because they will probably end up being used for other purposes.

What is more important is your choice of blog post title - I usually put a lot of work into this one thing alone. Next, try and include the blog post title in the URL. Finally, use social media links for all their worth! Quality links back to your blog will reap the most benefit SEO-wise :)

Friendly URLs always help and are included when using [BlogEngine](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/).

**UPDATE:**

To "canonicalize" your URLs, you can use ASP.NET routing or do it like this:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2009/02/21/ASPNET-SEO-and-the-Canonical-Tag.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the input but I do see that Google still view description meta tag as legit.

Comment: Yes, they are and it's good sense to use it. But, it's not used anymore for SEO purposes. Same holds true for the other major search engines now: Bing and Yahoo (Bing dressed up) :)

Comment: Legit? maybe, not sure what that means, but google has stated definitively that they [do _not_ use meta tags for page rank](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html). This is pretty much true of any page content that the user doesn't see. The SEO blackhats have so thoroughly polluted these attributes that they are useless to the search engines.

Answer (score 1):

The [meta keywords tag has no SEO value of any kind](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) and can be ignored.

The meta description tag does not affect rankings but [may be used by Google as the snippet below a page's listing in the search results](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/09/improve-snippets-with-meta-description.html).

The rel="canonical" tag is used to signify the preferred URL when content can be found using more then one URL.

The r[obots meta tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html) can be used to tell search engines not to index certain content or follow links on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Meta tags are very important for websites **SEO** you can't ignored them.Without these meta tags your site cannot get good **SEO** score and position on search engines.

important meta tags are following:

**1. Meta Title**

**2. Meta Description**

**3. Meta Keywords**

**4. Meat Robots**

For more deatils about these tags visit: 
[**https://blogging4uever.blogspot.com**](https://blogging4uever.blogspot.com/2017/05/5-killer-seo-tips-google-blogger-blog.html)

Answer (score -1):

For Google Panda title is very important. Keywords are not very important but you can use them.

Title, Description and Tags.